# Access INSERT/Block content in DXF with ezdxf

Tags: python, dxf

I'm trying to draw the content of a DXF file to an image, using python 2.7 and the ezdxf module.

I achieve to read and draw LINE, POLYLINE, CIRCLE, but I don't know what to do with the INSERT element.
I suppose this INSERT element (or the related block) contains other elements, LINE, POLYLINE and so on ... Right ?

Here is how i access basics DXF elements :

```
dwg = ezdxf.readfile(filename)
modelspace = dwg.modelspace()
for e in modelspace:
   analyseElement(e)

def analyseElement(e):
   if e.dxftype() == 'LINE':
       print("DXF LINE FOUND:")
       p1=e.dxf.start
       p2=e.dxf.end
      [...]
```

Can I hope to explore and extract basics elements from the INSERT contents ?
Thank you all !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A BLOCK is a reusable collection of entities and can be used like the model space to search or add DXF entities.

The INSERT entity is a block reference, which determines the place, the size and the rotation of the inserted block entities. And INSERT can have additional ATTRIB entities, which are text values referenced by a tag (name).

The BLOCK definitions are stored in Drawing.blocks property:

```
# iterate over all existing block definitions
for block in dwg.blocks:
    for e in block:
        analyseElement(e)
```

The INSERT entity is stored in the model space or in another block definition:

```
for insert in modelspace.query('INSERT'):
    block = dwg.blocks[insert.dxf.name]
    for e in block:
         analyseElement(e)
```

To search for specific INSERT entities:

```
for insert in modelspace.query('INSERT[name=="MyBlock"]'):
    ...
```

- Docs for blocks: http://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/blocks.html
- Docs for query: http://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/getting_data.html

Comment: It worked wonderfully ! Thanks mozman for your help and for this excellent ezdxf :)

Comment: the links for the blocks and query dont work , can u please post the updated links